# jQuery highlight text of individual column in table rather than across whole table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery that allows me to highlight all `td` across all of my html table that exceeds a threshold, in this case 13:

```
var table = document.getElementById('my_table');
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var cells = tbody.getElementsByTagName('td');
var specificheader = tbody.getElementsByTagName('th');

for (var i=0, len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
  if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) > 13){
    cells[i].className = 'red';
}
else if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) < -0.1){
    cells[i].className = 'green';}
}
```

With the corresponding HTML:

```
<table id="my_table">
<thead>
<tr style="text-align: right;">
  <th></th>
  <th>Vibration 1</th>
  <th>Vibration 2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th>2018-05-14</th>
  <td>0.02</td>
  <td>0.09</td>
  <td>0.11</td>
  <td class="red">13.26</td>
  <td>1.72</td>
  <td class="red">14.98</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>2018-05-15</th>
  <td>0.02</td>
  <td>0.05</td>
  <td>0.07</td>
  <td class="red">13.27</td>
  <td>1.54</td>
  <td class="red">14.82</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How would I restrict this to highlight only a on specific `th`, say Vibration 2?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is not much clear. Try to show your expected output.

Comment: @AnkurR - See how two columns are highlighted red when a threshold value is exceed here: https://i.imgur.com/HQxfx0u.png - I was asking, how can I just highlight values over my threshold in just *one* column instead of all columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might sort of a simple way.  You can just change your javascript to select the nth-child() of the tr's:

```
var cells = tbody.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(7)');
```

You could probably do something with that to make it dynamic so you can do what you want to programmatically.  I think it actually counts the th cells as a child.

Comment: Short and succinct, this does the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even though a table presents a 2d table, html nodes hierarchy is only one dimensional, so you can't just highlight a column

A possible solution may be premarking all td tags with a class of column number, say something like

```
<tr>
<td class="col-1">123</td>
<td class="col-2">4.56</td>
...
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="col-1">1234</td>
<td class="col-2">4.567</td>
...
</tr>
```

Then adding a condition to the jQuery accordingly
A basic implementation:

```
for (var i=0, len=cells.length; i<len; i++){ if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10) > 13){ 
var colcol = cells[i].getAttribute("class");

var tds = document.getElementsByClassName(colcol);
for (var j = 0;j < tds.length ;j++) {
 (tds[j]).addClass('red');
}
```

Notice that if the td has more than one class, we'll need to get just the column class
Which can be done by using split on the colcol var then taking the 1st class
or using regexp etc.